# Sending json api object using postman

Tags: json, json-api, jsonapi-resources, jsonapiframework

I am using JSONAPI Specification http://jsonapi.org/format/#status

And I have data like below,

```
{
  "data": 
    {
    "type": "tag",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
        "name": "Test"
    }
  }
}
```

How do I make a post request to the end point using postman chrome extension ?

I am trying to make a call but I cannot get the params.

Obs. I already set my Content-Type as `application/vnd.api+json`

Thanks !

[image: valid HTML]

Comment: Is this hosted globally? anyway we can test this from our local machines?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Select

METHOD `POST`

Then under Body chose `raw`

here is a screenshot

[image]on/json

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but unfortunately Im getting this erro   JSONAPI::Parser::InvalidDocument: A JSON object MUST be at the root of every JSONAPI request and response containing data. Also, the params and raw are coming as empty @raw={}, @params={}

Comment: @MauricioJunior Can you show us what you had in your postman?

Comment: @Coder Ive added the photo in the body

Comment: I know it's a little late, but depending on the server implementation, you have to set the header "Content-type" to "application/vnd.api+json."